# How to get return value from child process to parent?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, ipc, child-process

I'm supposed to return the sum of first 12 terms of Fibonacci series from child process to parent one but instead having `377`, parent gets `30976`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int i, fib_sum=0, fib1=1, fib2=1, temp, status;

    childpid=fork();

    if(childpid!=0)
    {
        wait(&status);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", status);
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=1; i<=12; i++)
        {
            temp=fib1;
            fib_sum=fib1+fib2;
            fib1=fib_sum;
            fib2=temp;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", fib_sum);
        return fib_sum;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use the process exit status, because on most systems, it has a very limited range (typically 0 to 127, inclusive). Use a pipe instead.

Comment: You can't use the child return code to return the value. It gets truncated to 7 bits. You'll need to set up a pipe or have child print value to a file that the parent can then read. Also, to get `fib_sum` in the parent, it is `fib_sum = (status >> 8) & 0x7F`

Comment: Use a pipe to pass data between the processes.

Comment: I can't use pipes because this is an exercise for my college class. Is there any other way?

Comment: How is it being an exercise stops you from using pipes?

Comment: if you need to get data from the child, you can use a shared global variable that the child updates, and when the parent detects that the child is completed, it would have stored the sum in the shared global.

Comment: How would you share that global variable? @bruceg. He has to make a shared memory.

Comment: I would have the child print the result to stdout, and have the parent invoke the child with `popen()`, and read the result.

Comment: @TonyTannous he's just forking the same program. he would just declare some shared memory object at the global level

Comment: You can pass an `int` (or an `uintptr_t`) using [`sigqueue()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html) and [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) in POSIXy systems, if a pipe or socket is not allowed.

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" you probably did not read the documentation to `wait()`, did you?

Comment: From [`man 2 wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html): "*WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)
              returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the
              least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child
              specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument
              for a return statement in main().*"

Comment: the exit value allows you only to pass back numbers in the range `0..255`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm supposed to return the sum of first 12 terms of Fibonacci series
>   from child process to parent one but instead having 377, parent gets
>   30976.

Process exit status is limited in value, therefore it is not the best way to communicate a value between child and parent.

One of the solution is to pass the calculated value  using pipes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int i, fib_sum=0, fib1=1, fib2=1, temp, status;

    int fd[2];
    int val = 0;

    // create pipe descriptors
    pipe(fd);

    childpid = fork();
    if(childpid != 0)  // parent
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        // read the data (blocking operation)
        read(fd[0], &val, sizeof(val));

        printf("Parent received value: %d\n", val);
        // close the read-descriptor
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    else  // child
    {
        // writing only, no need for read-descriptor:
        close(fd[0]);

        for(i=1; i<=12; i++)
        {
            temp = fib1;
            fib_sum = fib1+fib2;
            fib1 = fib_sum;
            fib2 = temp;
        }

        // send the value on the write-descriptor:
        write(fd[1], &fib_sum, sizeof(fib_sum)); 
        printf("Child send value: %d\n", fib_sum);

        // close the write descriptor:
        close(fd[1]);

        return fib_sum;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Child send value: 377                                                                                                                         
Parent received value: 377
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't [use pipes](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html), which would be the optimal solution here, you could save the result to a file that the parent would read from. Pass the name of the file to save the result to from parent to child. In your child process, you would do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fib_sum=0;
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        print_usage();
        return 1;
    }
    //... calculate fib_sum
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(f, "%d", fib_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Then in your parent process:

```
int n = 0;
FILE* f;
//... spawn child and wait
FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "r");
fscanf(f, "%d", &n);
```